# como situar fotos a la derecha o a la izquierda con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Hola tengo el siguiente menú en un barnner:

[image: Pantallazo del HTML]

El problema esta en la siguiente parte del codigo

```
<!--Nav banner: page ico, social networks and buy car-->
            <div class="navBar">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <!--page barner ico-->
                            <div class="pageIco">
                                <img src="img/ico/JPBico.png" class="ico">
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="navButtons">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <img src="img/ico/facebook.png" class="socialIco">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <img src="img/ico/instagram.png" class="socialIco">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <img src="img/ico/buycar.png" class="carIco">
                                        </div>     
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--END Nav banner: page ico, social networks and buy car-->    
            </div>
```

Pudes ver el codigo: https://github.com/felipedelosh/ecomerceFuneraria en el index lineas 30 a 60 la cosa es que intento que los iconos sociales se queden a la derecha y no lo consigo.

Alguien podria ayudarme para que mi pagina se vea de la siguiente manera:

[image: Imagen photoshopeada]

Comment: Soy nuevo, pongo el fracmento de codigo?

Comment: Listo acabo de agregar el div

Comment: solo a tu container padre dale display: flex; justify-content- flex-end, en bootstrap seria; d-flex justify-content-end

Comment: @BetaM a entonces el deberia hacer el logo de la empresa fuera del la lista del nav y darle al  nav d-flex ustifty-content- space-between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <!--Required meta tags-->
        <meta name="author" content="FelipedelosH">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="title" content="JPBGLOBALCOMERCIALIZADORA">
        <title>JPB Global comercializadora</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/ico/JPBIcoMin.png" />
        
        <!--Bootstrap-->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!--My styles css-->
        <link href="css/mainPageStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        
        </head>
    <body> 
        <!--Bootstrap-->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--Page Content-->
        <div class="mainPage">
            <!--Whatssap Button-->
            <div class="btnWhatsapp">
                <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+573104234025&text=test" target="_blank"><img src="img/ico/whatsapp.png"></a>
            </div>
            <!--Whatssap Button-->
            <!--Nav banner: page ico, social networks and buy car-->
            <div class="navBar">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <!--page barner ico-->
                            <div class="pageIco">
                                <img src="img/ico/JPBico.png" class="ico">
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="navButtons">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2 ms-auto">
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <img src="img/ico/facebook.png" class="socialIco">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2 ">
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <img src="img/ico/instagram.png" class="socialIco">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <div class="social">
                                            <img src="img/ico/buycar.png" class="carIco">
                                        </div>     
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--END Nav banner: page ico, social networks and buy car-->    
            </div>

            <!--Form-->
            <div class="form">
            <!--END Form-->
            </div>

            <!--TitleMisionVision-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Soluciones JPB global comercializadora</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa enim earum molestias consequuntur</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Products and solutions-->
            </div class="solutions">
            <!--END Products and solutions-->
            </div>

            <!--Video-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" id="video"> 
                        <video controls id="videoBackground" muted autoplay loop class="videoContainer">
                            <source src="media/mortuaryPrinter.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--END Video-->
            </div>

            <!--Solutions-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="mainSolutionIcons">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionMovil">
                                <img src="img/ico/movil.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Movil</p>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionPos">
                                <img src="img/ico/pos.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>POS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionEtiquetas">
                                <img src="img/ico/etiquetas.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Etiquetas</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSinRevestimiento">
                                <img src="img/ico/sin-revestimiento.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Sin revestimiento</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionKioscos">
                                <img src="img/ico/kioscos.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Kioscos</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSuministros">
                                <img src="img/ico/suministros.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Suministros</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <div class="solutionSoftware">
                                <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                <p>Software</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="text-center" style="background: yellow;">Nuestras soluciones</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="background: pink;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="solution">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>A</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="solution">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>A</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="solution">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>A</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="solution">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>A</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="solution">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>A</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="solution">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <img src="img/ico/software.jpg" class="solutionIco">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <p>A</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!--END Solutions-->
            </div>

            <!--History-->
            <div class="history">
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="img/history.jpg" class="imgHistory">
                </div>
            <!--END History-->
            </div>

            <!--Legend-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="legend">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa enim earum molestias consequuntur, porro eos quidem officia nesciunt eum. Voluptatum consequatur ullam nemo distinctio sapiente sed reiciendis iste veniam deserunt!</h1>
                </div>
            <!--END Legend-->
            </div>

            <!--Footer-->
            <div class="footer">
                <p class="text-center" id="copyright">2020</p>
            <!--END Footer-->
            </div>
            
        <!--END Page Content-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copie y pegue y yo la veo exactamene igual. :/

Comment: Holaaaaa, amigo muchas gracias tu respuesta es correcta, la cosa es que olvide limpiar la cache del navegador :) entonces por eso no me mostraba nadita gracias <3

Answer (score 1):

La solución puede plantearse de la siguiente forma:

- Usaremos [**flexbox**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)
- A la imagen del globo terraqueo envuelvela dentro de un **`div`**
- Aprovechamos que las 3 imágenes restantes ya se encuentran dentro de un contenedor por separado
- A cada uno de los 2 contenedores anteriores dales un **ancho del 50%**
- La imagen del globo originalmente queda del lado izquierdo por lo que ahi no requerimos mayor intervención
- Ahora al contenedor de las 3 imágenes les aplicamos igualmente *flexbox* para centrar vertical y horizontalmente de manera mas simple, además de lograr el espacio que debe existir entre los 3 elementos

Código de muestra

```
<link href="ruta_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--sustitúyela por la real para que puedas ver el funcionamiento planteado-->
<style>
  img {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 50px;
  }
</style>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="bg-primary p-2 w-50">
      <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="align-items-center bg-danger d-flex justify-content-around p-2 w-50">
      <img src="" alt="">      
      <img src="" alt="">      
      <img src="" alt="">      
  </div>
</div>
```

**Notas importantes**

- El CSS que puse por separado fue solo para pruebas pues no coloqué imágenes y simule el espacio que ocupan, ese lo remueves cuando coloques las reales.
- Las clases CSS las puedes consultar directo en la documentación para conocer mas sobre su implementación